# I cannot access my containers logs through external IP.. In my cluster i have exposed mutliple ports and it is a backend application

Tags: logging, external, azure-aks, using

This is my deploy.yml and service.yml file when apply this my pods are working fine and and I'm seeing the pods logs. I need to access this logs through external Ip is there any way for that

this is my deploy.yml file

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: node-app-deployment
labels:
app: node-app
spec:
replicas: 2
selector:
matchLabels:
app: node-app
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: node-app
spec:
containers:
- name: node-app
image: multitenantacr.azurecr.io/xyz/application-core-services:247
ports:
- containerPort: 9000
- containerPort: 9091
- containerPort: 8098

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: acr-img-secret
      mountPath: /var/run/secrets/acr-img-secret
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: acr-img-secret
    secret:
      secretName: acr-img-secret
```

and this is my service.yml file

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: my-app-service
spec:
selector:
app: node-app
ports:
- name: port1
port: 9000
targetPort: 9000
- name: grpc
port: 9091
targetPort: 9091
- name: port3
port: 8098
targetPort: 8098
type: LoadBalancer

and when I run kubectl get services
my-app-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.26.116   20.246.169.52   9000:31491/TCP,9091:30607/TCP,8098:30819/TCP

this is my external Ip  20.246.169.52 and try to ping or curl with any specific port it is not responding anything